# How to pass one or more arguments in Lambda expression in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

```
var itemInventoryUpdate2 = db.ItemInventoryDatas
     .Single(items => items.ItemId == item.ItemId );
```

Hi How can I convert above code so that I can pass to multiple arguments like it will select not just for Item Id but also for the location Id.

Answer (score 0):

use AND operator.

```
  var itemInventoryUpdate2 = db.ItemInventoryDatas.Single(items => items.ItemId == item.ItemId && items.LocationId == item.LocationId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [boolean logical operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators)  inside lambdas:

```
var itemInventoryUpdate2 = db.ItemInventoryDatas
     .Single(items => items.ItemId == item.ItemId && items.LocationId == item.LocationId);
```

Also if you want to concatenate multiple AND conditions you can specify multiple `Where` clauses:

```
var itemInventoryUpdate2 = db.ItemInventoryDatas
     .Where(items => items.ItemId == item.ItemId)
     .Where(items => items.LocationId == item.LocationId)
     .Single();
```